# Are there sequences in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which converge monotonically in a strong sense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples

Let $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convergent sequence whose limit is $x$.

**(Invented) definition:** We say that $x_n$ *converges monotonically* to $x$, if for every open *connected* neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, it holds that
$$
(x_{n_0} \in U  \,\,\text{ and }\,\,\, n>n_0)\,\,\, \Longrightarrow \,\,\,x_{n} \in U.
$$

**Question:** Do there exist pairwise distinct, monotonically convergent sequences $x_n$ in the sense defined above?

Even the sequence $x_n=(\frac{1}{n},0)$ in the plane, does not seem to converge monotonically, since we can "test" it with neighbourhoods $U$, which have "Rainbow-like" shape, thus skipping some of the elements of the sequence.

> It seems that for every potential sequence, we can  construct some $U$ which skips an element of the sequence, thus there shouldn't be such sequences. Am I right?

---

My motivation was to try to find a "topological" definition of monotone convergence, which generalizes $\|x_n-x\| \searrow 0$.

Comment: Every point will be isolated by the pairwise disjoint condition so you can build a little ball around any point and walk around it. You're spoiled for choice.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by $||x_n - x|| \searrow 0$. Doesn't the alternating harmonic series also satisfy this?

Comment: @legionwhale Yes, it does, you are right. The idea was to try to define what does it mean to "converge monotonically", i.e. to have the distance $d(x_n,x)$ to be decreasing. So not monotone convergence in the usual "order sense" on the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $x\in \Bbb R^m$ with $m\geqslant 2$, and assume that $(x_n)$ takes pairwise distinct values.
Let $n_0$ be such that $x_{n_0} \neq x_{n_0+1}$ and $x_{n_0+1}\neq x$.
Let $U= \Bbb R^m \setminus \{x_{n_0+1}\}$.
Then $U$ is a connected open neighbourhood of $x$, $x_{n_0} \in U$, but $x_{n_0+1} \notin U$.

Therefore, no converging sequence taking pairwise distinct values can satisfy your definition in dimension $m\geqslant 2$.

You can also build a simply-connected, bounded neighbourhood of $\{x,x_{n_0}\}$ that is disjoint from $x_{n_0+1}$, for instance by taking a tubular neighbourhood of a path joining them in $\Bbb R^m \setminus \{x_{n_0+1}\}$.

Maybe the notion of [uniform structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) is of interest though.

Comment: Thank you, that is a perfect answer. Very clear and elegant.

Comment: @AsafShachar You're welcome. I really think uniform structures are relevant for your question, since they give a notion of "$x$ is closer to $y$ than $z$". In your setting, it would give a notion of "$x_k$ is closer to $x$ than $x_n$ if $k>n$".

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. I will take a closer look at uniform structures. (which I only heard of but never looked into).

Comment: @AsafShachar I would say that it is of cultural interest, but I never encountered it anywhere else than in Bourbaki's textbooks to be fair. It is nevertheless important since it is a sort of minimal axiomatisation for a large number of results for metric spaces